# Running VBA on a shared mailbox Outlook 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, attachments, shared-mailbox

I have this code for saving attachments from e-mails with a specific sender and topic, down to my hard drive. It works fine when it is only working on my personal mailbox. But i need it to work with the shared mailbox i have with my co-workers.

I have this code in the "ThisOutlookSession":

```
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
 Dim objNS As NameSpace
 Set objNS = Application.Session

 Set olInboxItems = GetFolderPath("name of the shared mailbox\Inbox").Items
 Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Only act if it's a MailItem
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
    If (Msg.SenderName = "Sender name") And _
        (Msg.Subject = "test") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

        'Set folder to save in.
        Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
        Dim Att As String

        'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
        Const attPath As String = "U:\TESTING\"

        ' save attachment
        Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
        Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
        myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

        ' mark as read
        Msg.UnRead = False
    End If

End If

ProgramExit:
 Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
 MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
 Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Then i have this GetFolderPath function in my module:

```
' Use the GetFolderPath function to find a folder in non-default mailboxes
Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
 Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim FoldersArray As Variant
 Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
    FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
End If
'Convert folderpath to array
FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.item(FoldersArray(0))
If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
        Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
        Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
        Set oFolder = SubFolders.item(FoldersArray(i))
        If oFolder Is Nothing Then
            Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End If
'Return the oFolder
Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
Exit Function

GetFolderPath_Error:
 Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
 Exit Function
End Function
```

Do you have any suggestions to why it won't work?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you using, and do you have this shared mailbox connected as primary mailbox, or did you automatically got it after you gained rights to it?

Comment: Outlook 2016 and i am not actually sure of that. I got granted my work-mail, and everything was there i think. both my "personal" work mail and the shared mail.

Comment: @LPChip Outlook 2016

Comment: If, in Outlook, you go to File, Account Settings, Account Settings. Do you see the shared mailbox listed too? Or just your own account?

Comment: @LPChip Only my own account

Comment: That's why your code is not working. You need to add that shared mailbox as second account before VBA can find it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working, is because you need to add the shared mailbox as a second account. Only then will VBA be able to find the mailbox and work with it.

You can simply add the mailbox by providing the email address and a fake password. Once the login prompt comes, enter your own email address/username and password and it will be added as a second mail address.

Note, you have to close outlook and reopen it (maybe twice) before it will merge both accounts as one account. Otherwise you'll see it twice.

Comment: I have done that now, but the code doesn't work yet. It still doesn't save the attachment to the wanted folder :/ Is there something wrong in the code you think?

Comment: If the code works fine with your own account, then the code is fine. I don't know why it's not working though. VBA in outlook behaves really strange sometimes. You can try creating a new outlook account, first add the shared mailbox, and then your own, see if that works.

Comment: Okay, isn't there some way else? Because i've just seen that adding the shared mailbox creates some problems in the mailbox. For example shutting down every time i want to create a rule..

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But then again, I know a lot, but not everything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still a question anyone has but I have the answer for you.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/electronic-business-cards/using-events-with-automation

When using and event handler like this, it needs to be a class object.

For example
in class ClassModuleName:

```
Public WithEvents EventHandler As Items 'note the public it is required

Private Sub EventHandler_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 'note the change in name.

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Only act if it's a MailItem
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
    If (Msg.SenderName = "Sender name") And _
        (Msg.Subject = "test") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

        'Set folder to save in.
        Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
        Dim Att As String

        'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
        Const attPath As String = "U:\TESTING\"

        ' save attachment
        Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
        Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
        myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

        ' mark as read
        Msg.UnRead = False
    End If

End If

ProgramExit:
 Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
 MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
 Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

then in your actual session it will be:

```
    Dim AnyName as New ClassModuleName

    Private Sub Application_Startup()
        Dim objNS As NameSpace
        Set objNS = Application.Session
        Set AnyName= GetFolderPath("name of the shared mailbox\Inbox").Items
        Set objNS = Nothing
    End Sub
```

this initializes the handler as a new object and assigns it to the desired folder while giving it the event option "addItem"

Answer (score 0):

If `Set olInboxItems = GetFolderPath("name of the shared mailbox\Inbox").Items`

Then `Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)`